# Mimic browser hit from php script

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have a script which logs you into zencart when you open it in your browser.

Now when I try to call this from inside another php script using require, header, or curl, it does not login to zencart. It only works when the user opens the php script directly in their browser.

I also tried virtual(), but its running the index.php script for the top level of the site, not the file I specify. Thanks.

Comment: How does the script log you into zencart?

Comment: Steve, you must be understanding something fundamentally wrong. Please add more information about what you do, how your code looks like and your motivation to make it possible that helpful answers can be given - the part about zencart is clear.

Comment: what kind of script is the original script? you might need cookies which you _could_ do with curl, but seems like an odd approach.

Comment: Here is the script for logging into zencart. http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=4565&d=1222188402 I am trying to include it in a kohana application, so when the user logs into the kohana script they log into zencart. That way, I can use links in the kohana script and send them to checkout, preferably via AJAX.

Comment: What I did for a temp workaround was a javascript redirect. I will add a session variable to allow access to the bridge only by scripts on the servers. It really would be nice to eliminate the extra redirect page though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by reading the session from the database. Let me know if anyone is interested and I will open up a github. Thanks!